# AVR:Setting bits in C microcontroller

Tags: c, embedded, avr

I am trying to interface  ATmega328 with an LCDI have written the following code

```
#define en 28
```

the enable pin is 28,how can i set and reset this pin?

i am using atmel studio 6 with avrispmkii usb programmer

Comment: Which package is your chip? It matters which pin 28 is assigned to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consult [the datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8161.pdf) for your device.

Assuming you have the 28-pin PDIP package, we see that pin 28 is `PC5` (Port C, bit 5).

First you need to configure the pin as an output (1) using the Data Direction Register for port C, `DDRC`:

```
DDRC = (1<<DDC5);
```

Here, all other pins are configured as inputs (0).

Then to turn this pin on, OR on bit 5:

```
PORTC |= (1<<5);
```

To turn this pin off, AND off bit 5:

```
PORTC &= ~(1<<5);
```

See also:

- [I/O Port Operations in AVR](http://maxembedded.com/2011/06/10/port-operations-in-avr/)

Comment: to just toggle the bit, write a `1` to the corresponding bit in the corresponding `PIN` register: `PINC |= (1<<5);`

Comment: i take a look of your linked site. the explanations in the PIN-Sections are some kind of wrong. on the older AVRs the `PIN` regsiter is read only and must not be written (that the site does but states that this has no effect). On the newer AVR cores the `PIN` register is also writable and toggels the bits. Reading the `PIN` register is also independent of the `DDR` register. if the `DDR` is set to output then the `PIN` naturally reads a status that is equal to the `PORT` bit.